# SQL: what is the easiest way to replace normal emails in one of the columns with fake ones

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, email

In one of the tables of the database, we have a column which contains emails. The table is huge (over 500 000 items). 
I'm looking for a solution to replace existing emails with their "shuffled" or fake version (for testing purposes). As the email field is not mandatory, most of the cells are empty and I want to leave them in this way, so to replace only those which contain actual data (every 10th-30th row).

I found Red Gate http://www.red-gate.com and Fake.js, both look good and have positive reviews. However, it seems that for just one column, they are an overkill.

I'm not really good with SQL, I suppose that there may exist some ready scripts that can be applied to just one column to create fake data according to some regex rule.

Comment: just run an update query with condition where email is not null or email != '' and put some suffix in email, like make abc@gmail.com to xyz123abc@gmail.com this will change all email and you still can get them back by removing the suffix.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the logic behind "faking" the emails?

Comment: Are you wanting to replace the email body or the email address?

Comment: Do you mean that the column contains email addresses or the actual email content?

Comment: @Gidil, I just want to avoid accidently sending anything while debugging test code or unittets, the probability of doing this low, but I don't feel good keeping and manipulating real user data.

Comment: I was talking about Email address, not email body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set up:

```
UPDATE `table` -- will make abc@gmail.com -> abc@gmail.com.test
  SET `email` = CONCAT(`email`, ".test")
  WHERE `email` <> "";
```

tear down:

```
UPDATE `table` -- will restore abc@gmail.com.test -> abc@gmail.com
  SET `email` = LEFT(`email`, LENGTH(`email`)-5)
  WHERE `email` LIKE "%.test";
```

Comment: This is a good idea. I was thinking of something more complicated, but this works perfectly.